# factor score formula in lavaan

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I would like get the factor scores of R/lavaan, achieved by a CFA model (single factor, 4 continuous indicators), by hand. Which is the formula (equation) as function of the observed indicators. In addition, I would like also get them by ordinal Likert indicators (again single factor). How I can get the continuous values that R/lavaan assigns to the Likert categories after the fit?

Many thanks in advance.

Best,

Comment: Do you have a particular type of factor score in mind?

Comment: No, a generic latent varibale score, implemented in lavaan package.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to CrossValidated Davide,

As Preston harkens to, there are different types of factor scores, and so you need to be specific about the kind you are wishing to compute--there isn't necessarily a *generic* factor score.

The seminal work in this area (IMO) is the paper, "[Regression Among Factor Scores](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02296196)", by Skrondal and Laake. The authors discuss there being two approaches to calculating factor scores: the *Regression* method and the *Bartlett* method (this, I suspect, was the clarification Preston was after). Importantly, Skrondal and Laake demonstrate that each method is better/worse suited for when the factor score is to be used in a particular role (either as an explanatory or response variable) in some sort of substantive model.

Anyways, you'll find the formula for each in their paper.

**References**

Skrondal, A., & Laake, P. (2001). Regression among factor scores. *Psychometrika*, 66(4), 563-575.